# GridView Cell selection from Filtered Row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am having troubles with Gridview in C#.

On the disposed table, I apply filtering (i.e. by id) and returns the row by the desired ID. What I am trying to do is get the value of a cell of the returned row and then display it in an independed textbox. Any ideas?

this is the code I use for filtered results:

```
private void txtSearchExpr_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchExpr.Text)) 
    { 
        dataGridEmpList.DataSource = MyExcel.FilterEmpList(cmbSearch.Text.ToString(), txtSearchExpr.Text.ToLower());
    } 
    else 
    { 
        dataGridEmpList.DataSource = MyExcel.PatientList; 
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms? WPF? ASP? ...?? __Always__ tag your question accordingly!

Comment: You can get the row number using Select((x,i) => ........

Comment: private void txtSearchExpr_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchExpr.Text))
            {
                dataGridEmpList.DataSource = MyExcel.FilterEmpList(cmbSearch.Text.ToString(), txtSearchExpr.Text.ToLower());
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridEmpList.DataSource = MyExcel.PatientList;
            }

        } //this is the code I use for filtered results

Comment: This is A windows form application that reads excel files. Basically a modified version of this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696864/Working-with-Excel-Using-Csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            //gets the value of the id from the id cell
            int id = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            //let's say we wany the person with id 5
            if (id == 5) //this is our guy 
            {
                //let's say the name is stored in the cell with index of 1 and we wanna show it in textbox1
                textBox1.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

so this will search all rows in your grid and when it finds a row with id of 5 it will take the value in name cell within the same row and put it the text box